# Need to do misalign for Heading levels

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm Having two sets of XML file, in that i want to use the same XSL code both of the input xml file.

My first xml file is:

```
<Body>
<h1>Child1</h1>
<p>Class1</p>
<h2>Child2</h2>
<p>Class2</p>
<h3>Child3</h3>
<p>Class3</p>
<h4>Child4</h4>
<p>Class4</p>
</Body>
```

XSL I Used for this:

```
<xsl:template match="Body">     
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
<topic>
<xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
<title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</title>

<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="self::h2">
<topic>
<xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
<title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</title>

<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h3">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="self::h3">
<topic>
<xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
<title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</title>

<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h4">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="self::h4">
<topic>
<xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
<title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</title>
<body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/></body>
</topic>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each-group>
</topic>                      
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each-group>
</topic>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</topic>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
<p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

I got the output like below:

```
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title>Child1</title>
   <body>
      <p>Class1</p>
   </body>
   <topic id="topic_2">
      <title>Child2</title>
      <body>
         <p>Class2</p>
      </body>
      <topic id="topic_3">
         <title>Child3</title>
         <body>
            <p>Class3</p>
         </body>
         <topic id="topic_4">
            <title>Child4</title>
            <body>
               <p>Class4</p>
            </body>
         </topic>
      </topic>
   </topic>
</topic>
```

Now my Second XML is (there is not having h2):

```
<Body>
<h1>Child1</h1>
<p>Class1</p>
<h3>Child3</h3>
<p>Class3</p>
<h4>Child4</h4>
<p>Class4</p>
</Body>
```

My expected output for the second XML would be like:

```
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title>Child1</title>
   <body>
      <p>Class1</p>
   </body>
   <topic id="topic_2">
      <title/>
      <body/>
      <topic id="topic_3">
         <title>Child3</title>
         <body>
            <p>Class3</p>
         </body>
         <topic id="topic_4">
            <title>Child4</title>
            <body>
               <p>Class4</p>
            </body>
         </topic>
      </topic>
   </topic>
</topic>
```

For i need to get this output. How I have to change the XSL code which I mentioned above. I don't need the new coding for this. I want to edit the excisting above XSL code. Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no, easy, direct fix to the existing code as obviously, for instance, with a different input structure, with elements missing, the `<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/>` will fail, you can neither count nor group elements that don't exist. Have you considered a two step approach, where the first step adds missing elements and the second then applies your existing code? You will have to carefully specify and implement the first step.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @MartinHonnen. Shall I create separate template for the second method or else can any other method available means also provide me.

Comment: I would suggest to implement the first transformation step that adds missing elements in a different mode, then process the input in that mode, storing the result in a variable, and then to process the variable content with your existing code.

Comment: @MartinHonnen. Thanks. I will try on this

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I have posted the answer for this. Please review and tell me. Is this correct or not. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this Question, the answer is here:

XSL I used for second xml is:

```
<xsl:template match="Body">     
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
<topic>
<xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
<title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</title>

<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="self::h2">
<topic>
<xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
<title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</title>

<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h3">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="self::h3">
<topic>
<xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
<title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</title>

<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h4">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="self::h4">
<topic>
<xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
<title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</title>
<body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/></body>
</topic>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each-group>
</topic>                      
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each-group>
</topic>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</topic>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Body[not(h2)]">     
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">
<topic>
<xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
<title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</title>

<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h3">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="self::h3">
<topic>
<xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
<title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</title>

<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h4">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="self::h4">
<topic>
<xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h3 | h4"/></xsl:attribute>
<title>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</title>


</topic>                      
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each-group>
</topic>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</topic>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
<p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
</xsl:template>
```